# Get Count of Subcategories who has no other subcategories

Tags: php

I am working on a system in which I have a list of categories and subcategories. I have followed the given db structure for this:

```
category_id | category_name | Parent_id
     1              India         0
     2              US            0
     3              Mumbai        1
     4              Delhi         1
     5              New Delhi     4
```

Now I have two main categories (India and US) and 3 subcategories of these two parent categories. I want to calculate the count of subcategories, which has no further subcategories, of the top most parent element i.e India and US

For e.g

```
   India
  /      \
Mumbai  Delhi
            \
           New Delhi
           /      \
         N1        N2
```

Now, I want parent id jsons with a count of subcategories who has no other subcategories.
In this case count should be 2 because Mumbai has no subcategories and New Delhi has no subcategories.

```
{"category_name" : "India", "Count" => "3"} // (Mumbai , N1, N2 because they have no further subcategories)
```

It should be done in loop for all the parent categories. I am trying to use get it using recursive function but not getting exact results.
Any help?

**EDIT:**
I have similar SQLFIDDLE for it but it is showing only the count of subcategories. I want count of subcategories which has no further subcategories.
Please refer to given link.
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19814/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to get child node count using below query.

```
SELECT c.id,c.Name,  COUNT(a.ID) as cnt
FROM tblparent c
INNER JOIN tblParent a
ON a.ParentID = c.ID
GROUP BY c.ID,c.Name
UNION
SELECT c.id,c.Name,  0 as cnt
FROM tblparent c
where  c.ID not in (select parentid from tblParent)
```

It will give you below result

```
1 India 2
2   USA 0
3   Mumbai  0
4   Delhi   1
5   New Delhi   0
```

Hope this will help you!

Thanks
Suresh

Comment: I am not getting how you write it. Can you please do it according to SQLFIDDLE I have provided.

Comment: SELECT c.catid,c.Name,  COUNT(a.catid) as cnt
FROM category c
INNER JOIN category a
ON a.pcatid = c.catid
GROUP BY c.pcatid,c.Name
UNION
SELECT c.pcatid,c.Name,  0 as cnt
FROM category c
where  c.catid not in (select pcatid from category)

Comment: See the results. It is not working as I am expecting. Please read my question again. There should be two parent categories in the output with count of those subcategories who has no further child elements.